# How should I go about using a temporarily changed copy of a DLL locally when it's been checked in to TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, tfs, locking

We have a Libraries folder where we keep third-party DLLs and our own utility DLLs for all applications to reference.  I want to do development against one of our utility DLLs and an application that consumes it at the same time.  But if I check out the library DLL to change it for temporary local use, TFS insists on checking it out exclusively, which trips other people up.  I understand the reasoning behind it doing that (hard/impossible to merge a DLL, so two people shouldn't be working on one at the same time), but I just want to mess with my local copy while I'm working on the library it represents.

I suppose I could delete my application's reference to the DLL and recreate the reference pointing to some other place, but of course this just begs for me to forget and check it in like that, which would obviously be bad.  Not to mention that this is a pain in the neck.

How should I proceed in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a server workspace that does not allow editing outwith TFS. In TFS 2012 local workspaces were introduced which do not have a read only flag for files and you are free to edit at will.

You can change your existing workspace in a few clicks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could just go into the file system and mark the file as writeable. Once you are happy the binary is good you could check it out, copy the new version of the file over and check it back in again. TFS marks binary files like this as locked for good reason, as you can't merge them in the way you can with textual content.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use a NuGet repository to manage your binary dependencies, instead of relying on binaries checked into source control.